# rpm complaining about /bin/su

Tags: rpm

I need to install a vendor package onto a non-default directory (say /opt). By default, package gets installed in /usr/local/bin directory.

If I use command `rpm -ivh package.x86_64.rpm  --root /opt` I get error message  `/bin/sh is needed by package.x86_64`. After doing  Google, my understanding is that it happens because rpm is looking for dependencies in /opt directory. Is that true?

Given that I don't have vendor SPEC file, is it possible to fix this problem somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want the rpm option --prefix, not --root. --prefix will install into a different root directory for relocatable rpms, whereas --root uses the path at --root "for all operations" (from the man page) even dependency checks.